# Ember deferred tasks prevent test-helper promises from resolving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, qunit, rsvp.js, ember-testing

I'm developing an Ember-based application with front-end integration testing using QUnit and Teaspoon. I'm currently trying to implement a new feature that involves regular server queries using recursive calls of `Ember.run.later`. In much simplified form, written in CoffeeScript, this code is:

```
App.Widget = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  update: ->
    widget = @
    options = {...}
    @store.findQuery('widget_children', options).then (data) ->
      (do stuff with data)
      Ember.run.later widget, widget.update, 10000
```

I then have a set of unrelated tests that involve clicking on various elements of the page (using the `click` helper in `Ember.Test`), similar to the following:

```
asyncTest 'Gadget modal displays on link click', 1, ->
  Ember.run ->
    click($('.gadget a')).then ->
      start()
      equal $('#gadget-modal').length, 1, "Gadget modal not present"
```

What I'm seeing right now is that when Teaspoon gets to a click test (with a `later` call pending due to the app setup), it performs the click correctly, but the promise never resolves and the actual test assertions are not tested.

I'm assuming that the promise is not resolving because the deferred `later` call is considered asynchronous behaviour that the `click` helper is waiting to be completed, except that when it completes it merely sets up another `later` call – so it is never resolved.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Testing will stall and wait while timers still exist before it continues in testing mode on certain async functions.

Are you consistently pushing things into the run loop?  If so this might be blocking the testing from continuing.

You might need to disable certain functionality when running in test mode.

Comment: Yeah, I basically ended up refactoring my code to disable my `update` calls in my testing apart from places I'm specifically testing that functionality.